# Facepile data-action not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facepile

I have an object type "Page" and an action type "Create" and I would like to implement this in my facepile. Where "twm_test" is my namespace.

```
<div class="fb-facepile" data-href="http://domain.com" data-action="twm_test:page.create" data-size="large" data-max-rows="1" data-width="669"></div>
```

But it remains to use like. Could this be because I haven't included the schema in my `<html>` tag or is my format perhaps wrong?

I have tried several values for data-action, this one made most sense to me...

Thank you in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/8yyJE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of data-action property may be wrong. You made action type as "Create", then value must be "twm_test:create", not "twm_test:page.create". You may be following the tutorial with built-in Action and Object and be confused. Only built-in Action are used like "news.reads" or "video.watches". Custom action used like "twm_test:create". 
The tutorial, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/, would be helpful for you.

Comment: I'll give this a try, I'll let you know how it went. Thanks for your reply.